# Phpoffice library cannot write more than 14 digit numbers

Tags: php, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

```
 $sheet->setCellValue("H221", $task->amount); //42.1234567894123
```

But writes "42.123456789412"

[Excell cell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKjZd.png)

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with PHPOffice. When you just try to use the value anywhere else you'll get the same result. This is most likely caused by the [`precision` configuration directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision). (Although with such number precision, you could also walk into the limits of what a number in PHP can hold.) You could consider using a string instead of a number.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i’ve used strings as well both causing same results. But  I’ve tried returning same amounts with response and got right amounts. I think this excel limitations.

Comment: I think @Ivar is true based on php documentation of [floating point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)